# Why is my stored procedure rolling back with out me declaring it to do so

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to import users from a custom users table that existed in the system into the .net membership provider tables.

I built a small application that delete's all pre existing users within the .net membership tables except for my own account. I wrote it this way so that each time I run the application it clears out anything I've added and re- enters all the user's data. This stored proc worked int eh past but ever since switching to this new instance of SQL Server 2005 Enterprise the delete transaction keeps rolling back

Here is the stored procedure I use to clear out all my data prior to writing the users back into the .net membership tables.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ClearAllUsers]

AS
begin

DECLARE @UserID  uniqueidentifier

    set @UserID = (SELECT     UserId
FROM         dbo.aspnet_Users
where (UserName = 'gianluca.sirianni'))


begin
Delete from  dbo.aspnet_Membership WHERE (dbo.aspnet_Membership.UserID !=  @UserID) 
end

begin
Delete from  dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles   WHERE (dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserID !=  @UserID) 
end

begin
Delete from  dbo.aspnet_Profile   WHERE ( dbo.aspnet_Profile.UserID !=  @UserID) 
end

begin
Delete from  dbo.aspnet_Users  WHERE (dbo.aspnet_Users.UserID !=  @UserID) 
end

end
```

Can some one suggest why my data may be rolling back? I'm fairly fluent in SQL statements but not on the transaction handling of the server itself.

Update:

I changed the above procedure to the following. Is this correct?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ClearAllUsers]

AS
BEGIN 

DECLARE @UserID  uniqueidentifier

    SET @UserID = (SELECT     UserId
FROM         dbo.aspnet_Users
WHERE (UserName = 'gianluca.sirianni'))


BEGIN TRAN
DELETE FROM  dbo.aspnet_Membership WHERE (dbo.aspnet_Membership.UserID !=  @UserID) 
COMMIT TRAN

BEGIN TRAN
DELETE FROM  dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles   WHERE (dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserID !=  @UserID) 
COMMIT TRAN

BEGIN TRAN
DELETE FROM dbo.aspnet_Profile   WHERE ( dbo.aspnet_Profile.UserID !=  @UserID) 
COMMIT TRAN

BEGIN TRAN
DELETE FROM  dbo.aspnet_Users  WHERE (dbo.aspnet_Users.UserID !=  @UserID) 
COMMIT TRAN

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because implicit transactions are turned on *AND* you don't explicitly commit your changes.
You can either set implicit transactions off by executing `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF`
 or put `COMMIT TRANSACTION` after your `DELETE` statements.